# Why does VLC ignore --width, --height, and seemingly any other command line options I feed it?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

VLC always opens with a gigantic window which is very annoying. So I want to make it open a small window. Reading the documentation at https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Video_options , I found this:

```
--width, --height <integer> sets the video window dimensions. By default, the video window size will be adjusted to match the video dimensions.
```

So I used them:

```
vlc.exe "D:\videos\clown_jumping_on_trampoline.mp4" --width 320 --height 240
```

VLC opens up, playing that video file in a gigantic window. It's nowhere near 320 x 240 pixels. I've also tried much smaller numbers -- same gigantic window.

In the past, I've tried to use other options for setting the volume and other things. All have been ignored by VLC.

Does VLC even have support for any of its options that are documented? It seems like they are ignored.

No other software behaves like this, so it cannot be "my fault". For example, the media player MPC-HC respects all of the arguments I send to it. (But it cannot be used for what I need VLC for, so I cannot use it for this.)

As the person commented, I have also tried with:

```
 --width="320" --height="240"
```

And:

```
--width="320"
```

No difference. It's entirely ignored.

Comment: Have you tried using **either** `--width` or `--height` rather than both?

Comment: @Tetsujin Now I have. Same problem. Entirely ignored.

Comment: I started reading the guide from the top - this was the first thing I found… "Note: Windows users have to use the --option-name="value" syntax instead of the --option-name value syntax."

Comment: @Tetsujin Doesn't matter if I use that format. It's entirely ignored...

Comment: Note: the options seem to be ignored also in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Plasma desktop (KDE), X11, VLC 3.0.8.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's interesting. I assumed that this was yet another case of "we'll silently not properly support Windows while pretending to", but according to you, it's the same on Linux as well... And yet this media player is constantly hailed to the skies as some great FOSS project? I don't understand it. It's broken beyond words.

Comment: Even more interesting: "--start-time" is actually respected, regardless of the format I use... So it's not even consistently all options that are ignored, clearly... Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

[The issue is explained in vlc official site](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/9931).

It was solved for future 4.0 version, so, we can wait and look to vlc roadmap timeline.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Why? Because that bug was solved for 4.0 future version, not yet available.
How they solved? Following bug history years ago they explained with details that now 
 strangely I can't find now.
I remember was surely solved.

Comment: workaround: use `ffplay`